# Every time I enter sculpt mode the mesh switches to faceted render, how do I avoid this?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I have a mesh I sculpted and when I switched to Layout mode, I saw there are some minor errors introduced by the sculpting (flipped polys, etc.).
I would like to correct them, but they really pop up only when I switch to smooth shading.
How do I avoid Blender to switch the object render to faceted each time I go sculpting?
Also, this switch affects the object permanently, and I always have to switch back to smooth shading. Shouldn't happen I think.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and upload images that show your 
current setup and illustrate the problem. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Ehm but there's nothing really to show, it's all well described in the post. A picture wouldn't add anything. A video maybe, but I don't think it's really necessary, when I've described the issue so well. Also, I don't know what picture to upload, of which settings... if I knew, maybe I would have solved the problem, and of course I can't post screenshots of all the settings panel of Blender...